# Is field injection not allowed in viewmodels?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am new to Dependency Injection in Android, and I am trying to apply it in my app using Hilt. I have a viewmodel annotated with `@HiltViewModel` and I'm trying to field inject a repository using the `@Inject` annotation. But I keep getting this error:

```
public final class AlarmsViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
             ^
  @HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AlarmsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var alarmsLiveData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Alarm>>()
    var alarmFormLiveData = MutableLiveData<Alarm>()
    @Inject lateinit var alarmsRepository: AlarmsRepository

    init {
        alarmFormLiveData.value = Alarm()
    }

    fun save() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            alarmsRepository.save(alarmFormLiveData.value!!)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the repostory I want to inject:

```
class AlarmsRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val alarmDao: AlarmDao
) {
    suspend fun load(): Flow<List<Alarm>> {
        return alarmDao.load()
    }

    suspend fun save(alarm: Alarm) {
        alarmDao.save(alarm)
    }
}
```

What do you think I am doing wrong? Maybe I misunderstood something.
Also the version of hilt I am using is 2.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as error says "@HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor."

your AlarmsViewModel is missing one

replace :

```
@HiltViewModel
class AlarmsViewModel : ViewModel()
```

with :

```
@HiltViewModel
class AlarmsViewModel @Inject constructor(var alarmsRepository: AlarmsRepository) : ViewModel()
```

and remove

```
@Inject lateinit var alarmsRepository: AlarmsRepository
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've actually already tried this and it worked. From what I understood from the android docs, HiltViewModel for viewmodels is the equivalent of AndroidEntryPoint for activities, fragments, etc. From their examples, they do field injections for classes that has AndroidEntryPoint annotation. So I thought I could also do the same for viewmodels. I guess the docs didn't clarify that you can only do constructor injection when using HiltViewModel

Answer (score 4):

I found out from the dagger docs(https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/hilt/android/lifecycle/HiltViewModel.html) that @HiltViewModel only accepts constructor injection. I think the android docs didn't clarify it. So the only fix to this problem is constructor injection like the answer posted by @Pratyush,